# Bazaar - effect of pushing, pulling, or merging with different releases and operating systems?

Tags: dvcs, bazaar

Suppose one person is using Bazaar 2.3 on Linux, and another is using Bazaar 2.5 on Windows.  Are there problems that may result from pushing, pulling, or merging between repositories on the different releases and operating systems?  Or is it designed to interoperate seamlessly across the different release versions and OS?  What about older and newer versions, say 2.6 and 2.2 -- will the compatibility similarly hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently versions 2.x are all compatible with each other.